# Retry Mechanism catching exception wont work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a retry mechanism for an API call to make the same request if the stated business logic occured. I made it really easy for now and will enchance it later with exceptionType handling etc. I simply throw exception if the logic happens and catch them in the retry mechanism but in below the code is just killing the thread and does not execute after the first try. Can you help me please what I am missing here ?

This is the retry logic I am trying to use.

```
    public static T Do<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int attemptCount)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        for (int attempted = 0; attempted < attemptCount; attempted++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (attempted > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
                }
                return action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
```

This is how I invoke the retry method.

```
    await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    RetryHelper.Do(() => ConfirmRequestRetryAsync(request, true), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 10);
                });
```

And this is the method which can throw exceptions due to logic.

```
    public async void ConfirmRequestRetryAsync(ConfirmRequest request, bool flag)
    {
        logger.Info($"Confirm Request Async Called for the request : {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)}");
        var confirmRequest = GetSignedConfirmRequest(request.PaymentId);
        var confirmResponse = await MakeRequest(confirmRequest);
        //Added flag and sending at false at first try to not throw exception
        //Then in retry mechanism this exceptions will be use to trigger retry logic.
        if (flag)
        {
            var statu = ConfirmResponseXmlConvert(confirmResponse);
            if (statu.Item1 == "0" && statu.Item2 == "InProcess")
            {
                throw new Exception("InProcess");
            }
            else if (statu.Item1 == "-1" && statu.Item2 != "Declined")
            {
                throw new Exception("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConfirmRequestRetryAsync` is an async void method. This means it will return at the first await. The rest of the code will run at some later time, in the same thread context as the caller. So when the exceptions are thrown the retrying method has already returned and there is nothing to catch the exceptions.

The fix is to make it an async Task method, and await this in your retry-method. This might require two variants of the retrying method, one for async methods and one for non-async.

A rule of thumb for async void is to never allow exceptions to be thrown from them, since there is no possibility for anyone to catch them. Always use async Task if exceptions is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @JonasH my retry method is working good with non asnyc methods but wanted to try on this method now I changed the "ConfirmRequestRetryAsync" to async Task and my invoke method is now  await Task.Run(() =>
{
RetryHelper.Do(async () => await ConfirmRequestRetryAsync(request, true), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 10);
});